# Python: overlapping (non exclusive) inheritance to have methods available based on instance parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I want to have certain attributes & methods only available in a class instance, if the parameters meet certain conditions. The different cases are not exclusive. I already have a working solution (incl. the suggestion from ShadowRanger):

```
class polygon():
    def __new__(cls, vert, axis=None):
        triangle = vert == 3
        solidrev = axis is not None
        if triangle and not solidrev:
            return super().__new__(_triangle)
        elif solidrev and not triangle:
            return super().__new__(_solid)
        elif solidrev and triangle:
            return super().__new__(_triangle_solid)
        else:
            return super().__new__(cls)
    def __init__(self, vert, axis=None):
        self.polygon_attribute = 1
    def polygon_method(self):
        print('polygon')

class _triangle(polygon):
    def __init__(self, vert, axis=None):
        super().__init__(vert, axis)
        self.triangle_attribute = 2
    def triangle_method(self):
        print('triangle')

class _solid(polygon):
    def __init__(self, vert, axis):
        super().__init__(vert, axis)
        self.solid_attribute = 3
    def solid_method(self):
        print('solid of revolution')

class _triangle_solid(_triangle, _solid):
    def __init__(self, vert, axis):
        super().__init__(vert, axis)
```

Availability of attributes & methods depends on the instance parameters:

- The attributes & methods from the base class should always be available.
- If the first parameter equals 3, the attributes & methods from subclass _triangle should be available.
- If the second parameter is defined, the attributes & methods from subclass _solid should be available.

All combinations:

```
P = polygon(2)
P = polygon(2,axis=0)
P = polygon(3)
P = polygon(3,axis=0)
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this? In the ideal case, I want to get rid of the _triangle_solid class. Also, I don't get why I need to define the default argument for axis in some cases but not all of them.

Full project: https://github.com/gerritnowald/polygon

Comment: why is `class polygon():` a class?

Comment: I merged polygonBase and polygon following the suggestion from ShadowRanger.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of trying to overdo use of inheritance. Inheritance makes logical sense when there is an "is a" relationship between the child and its parent class. A triangle is a polygon, so no problems there; it's a reasonable inheritance chain. A solid of revolution, while possibly built from a polygon, is not a polygon, and trying to wedge that into the inheritance hierarchy is creating problems. It's even worse because a solid of revolution may not even be defined in terms of a polygon at all.

I'd strongly recommend defining your solids of revolution with an attribute representing whatever is being revolved to produce it, not as a subclass of that revolved figure.

---

All that said, `polygon` itself should not be responsible for knowing all of its subclasses, and if it is, it should still be the parent of a triangle. Your design as currently rendered has a `polygon` class that *nothing* is an instance of; the `__new__` is returning something that is not a `polygon`, and that's confusing as heck. You can write the hierarchy in a safer, if still not idiomatic OO way, by doing:

```
# Tweaked name; it's not just the base anymore; using PEP8 class name capitalization rules
class Polygon:
    def __new__(cls, vert, *args, **kwargs):  # Accept and ignore the arguments we don't care
                                              # about, __init__ will handle them
        if vert == 3:
            return super().__new__(Triangle)
        else:
            return super().__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self, vert, axis):
        self.polygon_attribute = 1

    def polygon_method(self):
        print('polygon')

class Triangle(Polygon):
    def __init__(self, vert, axis):
        super().__init__(vert, axis)
        self.triangle_attribute = 2

    def triangle_method(self):
        print('triangle')

t = Polygon(3, None)
p = Polygon(4, None)
print(type(t), type(p))
# Indicates t is a Triangle, p is a Polygon
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZHBbsMgDIbvfQrfClFUaU1PlfIK0w67I9Y6KRojCJx1efoUkpDQy7T5ZOwf@7NtB7p1phrHi5bew1unh7Yz5x0Eu2IDQhi8C8Eu2pfwjY5KKKRrw6MoPu/R47M4mmomCdQ1VFs0mkPqnQHfW3SMH1LVd6ekaTXyVYza45@@BiC@yzCVURTCHnWTQOWPyuli6mDnAYUkcuqjJ4QaXrY6Kf2FYS3XqVpWwTpliO0X0T70n7eWxmDL@vj5f2DraIs2Uz3T09LoCf@44a/5X/mTKg4QjpWOzqoSXjsTjmGz4GkNTp9psMiIlzA5lvNxfAA)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I found a way to do what I want and updated my question to be more general parallel to you answering the old one. I will try to remove the empty base class like you recommend. I get your point that solid of revolution usually is not a polygon. In my case, this subclass adds only very little functionality which requires things defined in the base class, so solid of revolution has to be a subclass of polygon.

Comment: Also, the interface of `Polygon` may preclude making `Triangle` a subclass of `Polygon` as well. Suppose `Polygon.add_vertex` allows you to add a point to an n-gon to make it an `(n+1)-gon`. That's fine: n-gons and (n+1)-gons are still polygons. But you should *not* be able to use `add_vertex` to turn a `Triangle` into a 4-gon.

Comment: As a general rule, I would avoid trying to use `foo.__new__` as a factory function to create instances of subclasses of `foo`. Use a regular function, or define a dedicated class method to do this instead.

Comment: @GerritNowald "In my case, this subclass adds only very little functionality which requires things defined in the base class, so solid of revolution has to be a subclass of polygon." That does not follow at all. In fact, there really is never any reason something *has* to be a subclass.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: in my case, _solid can do everything polygon can, but not the other way around. So _solid should inherit from polygon. Maybe I have a false understanding what a subclass is.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: I updated my example according to your suggestion. For me, *args, **kwargs did not work because I need axis for the condition. I don't get why I need to define the default argument for axis in some cases but not all of them. I haven't completely understand this structure, is this recursive in a way?